# undefined symbol: xmlMemDisplayLast error with lxml

Tags: python, centos, lxml

I receive these errors on installing lxml via pip:

```
    running build_ext
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-i686-3.5
    creating build/temp.linux-i686-3.5/src
    creating build/temp.linux-i686-3.5/src/lxml
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/usr/local/include/python3.5m -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-3.5/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w
    In file included from src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:321:
    src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h:19:4: error: #error minimum required version of libxml2 is 2.7.0
    src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h:28:4: error: #error minimum required version of libxslt is 1.1.23
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_9XMLParser___init__’:
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:113201: error: ‘XML_PARSE_HUGE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:113201: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:113201: error: for each function it appears in.)
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_4lxml_5etree_10Schematron_6__call__’:
    src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:194047: error: ‘XML_SCHEMATRON_OUT_ERROR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    Compile failed: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    creating tmp
    cc -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /tmp/xmlXPathInitomumkupc.c -o tmp/xmlXPathInitomumkupc.o
    cc tmp/xmlXPathInitomumkupc.o -L/usr/lib -lxml2 -o a.out
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/bin/python3.5 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-2c9_3zz2/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-du99fdnt-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-2c9_3zz2/lxml/
```

Assuming some packages aren't meeting the requirement, I tried updating them via yum:

> Package libxml2-2.6.26-2.1.25.el5_11.i386 already installed and latest version
>
> Package libxslt-1.1.17-4.el5_8.3.i386 already installed and latest version

I am on CentOS with Python 3.5.1. Is there no straight forward way to have this installed?

Perhaps it's worth seeking out another yum repo?

If I try a manual install (libxslt 1.1.23 and libxml 2-2.7.2) via https://serverfault.com/questions/266927/install-libxml2-2-7-x-on-centos-5-x#305682 of these two packages to get them up-to-date, I get this error when trying to use lxml in Python 3.5:

```
>>> from lxml import html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from .. import etree
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lxml/etree.cpython-35m-i386-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: xmlMemDisplayLast
```

Comment: What about `libxslt`? That's the other lib you should have installed.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Yeah that's installed already `Package libxslt-1.1.17-4.el5_8.3.i386 already installed and latest version`

Comment: Given that messages `error minimum required version of libxml2 is 2.7.0` and `error minimum required version of libxslt is 1.1.23`, are you saying your problem is that you don't know how to get packages that satisfy these requirements installed on CENTOS?  Does this help: http://serverfault.com/questions/266927/install-libxml2-2-7-x-on-centos-5-x#305682?

Comment: @snakecharmerb I've tried manual installs only to be met with more errors, I'll add it into the question

Comment: So it looks like lxml now builds, but somehow has not compiled correctly.
Can you tell us: what versions of libxml2 and libxslt you have installed?  What versions of libxml2-devel and libxslt-devel you have installed?  What version of lxml did you install?

Comment: @snakecharmerb libxslt 1.1.23 and libxml 2-2.7.2. I did not touch devel yet, as I didn't see any tar.gz's on ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/

Comment: `tar.gz`s - did you build from source rather than using the rpms as described in the ServerFault answer?  If so the error on importing lxml suggests that the libs are not exposing all the symbols that lxml expects.

Comment: What about this question, wouldn't it help? http://serverfault.com/questions/266927/install-libxml2-2-7-x-on-centos-5-x

Comment: @snakecharmerb Oh, yes I did build from source (before I saw that link)

Answer (score 1):

```
src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h:19:4: error: #error minimum required version of libxml2 is 2.7.0
src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h:28:4: error: #error minimum required version of libxslt is 1.1.23
```

The version of libxml2-devel & libxslt-devel are not satisfied requirements.

try `yum install libxml2-devel libxslt-devel`

Comment: *Assuming some packages aren't meeting the requirement, I tried updating them via yum*, followed by package versions that are too old. They need help finding newer packages.